# SQL wrong sum when using join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum

I have this query:

```
SELECT     BLI.EmpID, ShortEmployees.EmpName1 AS EmpName, SUM(BLI.FinalValue) AS Total
FROM       BLI 
INNER JOIN BSR ON BLI.BLID = BSR.BLID 
INNER JOIN ShortEmployees ON BLI.EmpID = ShortEmployees.EmpID
WHERE     (CONVERT(varchar, BLI.BLDate, 112) >= CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, '1/10/2012', 103), 112)) 
AND (CONVERT(varchar, BLI.BLDate, 112)  <= CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(datetime, '30/10/2012', 103), 112)) 
AND (BSR.BSTID = 2) 
AND (BLI.State IN (2, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 18))
GROUP BY BLI.EmpID, ShortEmployees.EmpName1
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

I'm expecting the Total to be 42 but I get it triplicated 126!

EDIT: 
My expectations are wrong, the query returns the right sum.

Comment: check joins. Perhaps you expect to found one row in BSR for this BLID and they are 3.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? I'd like to find out what the CONVERT function does in your DBMS.

Comment: @Colin'tHart, SQLServer. [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) do a cast string to date.

Comment: I'm using SQLServer 2008, BLID is primary key for BSR so it's impossible to have 3 same row values.

Comment: @mhdali - From your comments here and on the question below, are you now saying that `126` really is the right result and there was never a problem in the first place?

Comment: Answer your own question please, saying "my bad, sql works great" :)

Answer (score 2):

Either BSR contains three records that match the BLI.BLID or ShortEmployees contains three records for BLI.EmpID.

Also why are you converting the dates to varchar? It looks like they're all dates in the first place. Replace your hardcoded dates from '1/10/2012' to the ansi standard of '2012-10-01'

Comment: A strong *AMEN* to "Why are you converting the dates to varchar?" For best performance in any DBMS, always compare datatypes in their native formats. Then the DBMS knows that 2012-04-01 follows immediately after 2012-03-31, with no possible intermediate values, whereas as a string there are many possible values in between.

Comment: @tobsey, Don't know why user should convert string dates 'British/French' to string dates 'ansi', change to datetime format has more sense. Also, perhaps you should wait to OP replies comments.

Comment: @danihp The question contains hardcoded dates in the british format. Then every date in his database is being converted to varchar. As Colin said above this is very bad practice. If the asker is adding dates to to the query as string literals then he should use the correct format.

Comment: BSR.BLID and ShortEmployees.EmpID are primary keys of their tables, so well... they have distinguish values.

Comment: Why I convert dates? because I'm using objective-c for my client side (iPad) and ASP.Net using c# for webservice.

Comment: @Mhdali BSR.BLID is a primary key? Isn't BLID the primary key of BLI and BSR.BLID not a foriegn key referencing BLI.BLID. I'd suggest you remove the `SUM` and `GROUP BY` statements and select all rows and all columns. That will show you where the data is being multiplied. You will likely find that one of your tables is being joined three times.

Comment: @Mhdali how are you passing the data from the web service to SQL? You could easily convert the date string to a `datetime` type in .net and pass that to SQL Server. If you must pass it as a string then format it to 'YYYY-MM-DD' in .net before passing it to the database. SQL will cast the string parameter to a datetime, but it won't need to convert any of the dates that are stored in your tables.

Comment: @Tobsey actually, BLID is the primary key of BSR, I didn't design the db and I don't know why the heck they did this! there are many other mistakes but I have to get over them, I did what you said and surprise me I was wrong :$ the query is giving me the correct sum, and my expectations are wrong.

Comment: @Tobsey Yes, from webservice to SQL, actually I just return the whole string query result as DataSet so I can easily convert it to xml and return it back to the iPad.

Comment: @Tobsey, I agree that date should be stored in database as a `date type`. But you don't talk about this in your answer. You say that date string should be represented in ansi format.

Comment: @Tobsey, you should reconsider your answer after this OP comment: 'BSR.BLID and ShortEmployees.EmpID are primary keys of their tables'

Comment: @danihp I've handled each of your points in comments here. OP has found source of his issue so I don't think this needs further consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding date format. For SQL Server use this date format 'YYYYMMDD'. SQL Server knows how to compare this date with date column within table.

So,
proper SQL Code could be like:

`WHERE BLI.BLDate >= '20121001' AND BLI.BLDate <= '20121030'`

or

`WHERE BLI.BLDate  BETWEEN '20121001' AND '20121030'`